# Facebook Omniauth gem not returning the correct information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

So Facebook omniauth was working perfectly fine on my rails site.
No it's not, and upon inspecting the returned data from facebook I see this:

```
{
  "provider": "facebook",
  "uid": "id",
  "info": {
    "nickname": "username",
    "email": "email",
    "name": "name",
    "first_name": "first_name",
    "last_name": "last_name",
    "image": "http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture",
    "description": "bio",
    "urls": {
      "Facebook": "link",
      "Website": "website"
    },
    "verified": "verified"
  },
  "credentials": {
    "token": "CAAUfds9x8Xf3f6VABfAFf8CQXwdmGFdpNo1f3Dqh3tjxDHmFCh4BvcawcxREJEEam9U1po2mWD7ejnDmDI3ZCKT5G3oOlZAkyHV3j5vNvToCmPpW8DnSBlheAGZADxLvLwPzf8cwVCMHhes0ZBfZAkL6basAPghFG1adAZCDG6FLSUlF1pwMAZD",
    "expires_at": 1405568757,
    "expires": true
  },
  "extra": {
    "raw_info": "{a ton of info here that is correct}"
  }
}
```

The part where is says "email": "email", it literally says that, it's not me changing values. The data I get returned is generic. Did Facebook change something recently...? How do I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], {:scope => 'basic_info, email, offline_access', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}} 
  else
    config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], {:scope => 'basic_info, email', :client_options => {:ssl => {:verify => false}}}
  end
```

#OmniauthCallbacksController

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    debugger
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      if @user.status == "inactive"
        redirect_to reactivate_user_page_path(@user) 
      else
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
      end
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:
This is only happening in development, not in production. So maybe there's something wrong on the facebook app settings.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my working code, In `find_for_facebook_oauth` method, i am passing `current_user`

```
  def facebook        
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

Comment: So the problem is in request.env['omniauth.auth'] and the data that it's returning. It is not returning facebook data, it's returning literally "name" => "name", "username" => "username". Basically useless information for everyone who logs in.